# Vue, conditional for putting values into an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a call in my Vue site that returns a response.data object which contains a date:

**An object in `response.data` looks like:**

```
response.data = {available_at: '2019-08-12', title: 'Test'}
```

I'm currently fetching that and building an array called `dates` with `this.dates` which works fine. But, I'm wondering if there's a way where I can say `if response.data.available_at = current_date` then put in `this.dates`, `else` put in `this.pastDates`

Is there a way to modify this to do so?

```
fetch() {
    axios.get('/items/')
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data)
      this.dates = response.data
    })
    .finally(function() {})
}
```

**UPDATE: response.data** (a list of objects)

```
(51) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…},...]
0:
available_at: "2019-09-16"
title: "2"
```

Comment: do u mean?: `response.data = {available_at: '2019-08-12', title: 'Test'}` array isn't same that object

Comment: Yes sorry, that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the date a string? Maybe you can use something like this then:

```
if (response.data.available_at === new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)) {
//add to this.dates
} else {
// add to this.pastDates
}
```

Okay, the response.data is a list of these objects. So it would go something like this:

```
response.data.forEach(item => {
    if (item.available_at === new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)) {
        this.dates.push(item);
    } else {
        this.pastDates.push(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: ```if (response.data.available_at === new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)) {
            this.dates = response.data
          }``` This doesn't seem to work

Comment: available_at in console is "2019-09-17" and dumping the new Date portion just shows 2019-09-17 with no quotes

Comment: Wait, response.data.available_at prints undefined in your example. That's why it's not working

Comment: You cannot define a list like this: `var data = [available_at: '2019-08-12', title: 'Test']`. Is it actually an object like `var data = {available_at: '2019-08-12', title: 'Test'}` ?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant initially, I used the wron brackets. But response.data.available_at is returning undefined

Comment: log out response.data. Maybe there is a type in available_at

Comment: there isn't, it logs response.data, but no tertiary value like available_at or title

Comment: ```this.tempDates = response.data
          if(this.tempDates.available_at === new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)){
            this.dateEvents = tempDates
          }
          console.log(this.tempDates.available_at)``` Tried it this way too but still undefined

Comment: add the console.log(response.data) to your SO question

Comment: I edited my comment, look how i used .forEach to iterate over the response.data list.